# GPL - No version mentioned

Tags: licensing, open-source, gpl

```
This software is allowed to use under GPL or you need to obtain Commercial License 
 to use it in non-GPL project.
```

The above is mentioned on an open source project. It does not mention GPLv3 or GPLv2 explicitly. Does that mean I can use it as GPLv2/3 as per my convenience (as we can with LGPL)

I'm an open source newbie, so I just want to clarify this.

Comment: Without knowing what project you're referring to or where you saw the claims of GPL licensing, there's no way anyone can answer your question.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6489#6489

Comment: I recommend contacting the authors/copyright holders and asking them to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

[GPLv1](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-1.0.html) §7 states:

> …Each version is given a distinguishing version number.  If the Program
>   specifies a version number of the license which applies to it and "any
>   later version", you have the option of following the terms and conditions
>   either of that version or of any later version published by the Free
>   Software Foundation.  **If the Program does not specify a version number of
>   the license, you may choose any version ever published by the Free Software
>   Foundation**. [emphasis mine]

As [o11c noted](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/258027/1860), GPLv1 was more permissive than later versions, and there's the chapter and verse that lets you choose.

Comment: GNU [GPLv2 (§9)](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html) and [v3 (§14)](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) states the same.

Answer (score 0):

If no version is mentioned, you can use it under any version of the GPL, including version 1. It is for this reason that "any version" is not recommended, because the GPLv1 is much weaker than GPLv2 or GPLv3.